# A parameter list without types is only allowed in a function definition

Tags: objective-c, xcode, unity-game-engine, fbsdk

When I `xcodebuild` the Unity project, I get an error. I am using Xcode 3.2, with architectures armv7/arm64, deployment target 9.0.

```
- (void)_setSessionCompletionHandlerFromHandler:(void(^)(BOOL, NSError *))handler
{
    __weak typeof(self); weakSelf = self;
  _authenticationSessionCompletionHandler = ^ (NSURL *aURL, NSError *error) {
    typeof(self) strongSelf = weakSelf;
    strongSelf->_isRequestingSFAuthenticationSession = NO;
    handler(error == nil, error);
    if (error == nil) {
      [strongSelf application:[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:aURL sourceApplication:@"com.apple" annotation:nil];
    }
    strongSelf->_authenticationSession = nil;
    strongSelf->_authenticationSessionCompletionHandler = nil;
  };
}
```

The error messages are:

```
Use of undeclared identifier 'strongSelf'
A parameter list without types is only allowed in a function definition
Use of undeclared identifier 'weakSelf'
```

Comment: The current version of Xcode is around 10.2. Are you really using Xcode 3.2?

Comment: What version of Unity are you using?

Comment: Xcode project format 3.2 version 10.2.1

Comment: Unity 2018.3.9f1

Comment: Remove the `;` in the middle of `__weak typeof(self); weakSelf = self`.

Comment: sorry did not improve, it's want   `;`

Comment: I fixed -     `typeof` instead     `__typeof`